# How to define default dictionary keys for sub-classed from built-in dictionary class

Tags: python

`SubClass()` is a sub-class of built-in Python dictionary:

```
class SubClass(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SubClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now with any dictionary variable I can declare an instance of `SubClass`. Each dictionary key will become a key of SubClassed instance automatically (which is pretty cool):

```
myDictionary={'city':'New York', 'year':2014}
instance=SubClass(myDictionary)
print instance['city']
print instance.keys(), instance.values(), instance.items()
```

I would like to define a set of default dictionary keys so each `SubClass` object (instance) gets them on declaration. I could:

```
class SubClass(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SubClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self['id']=None
        self['number']=None
        self['oneMoreDefaultKey']=None
```

But that takes a lot of typing and looks ugly. I rather would like to achieve the same with a minimum amount of code.

Comment: if you are simply trying to avoid `if key_name in _dict:`, just use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: Should I put `defaultdict['key1','key2','key3`]` in `__init__` of `SubClass()`? Please post an answer with example!

Comment: What do you mean by "lots of typing and looks ugly"? It's 3 lines of code, it's difficult to imagine it getting too much shorter... Also, `defaultdict` is for when you want your dictionary to return a particular value when it's missing a particular key, rather than throwing a `KeyError`, which isn't what you describe.

Comment: @PatrickCollins, I think OP is saying that the reptitive `self[...]=None` is not [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

Comment: @Robᵩ I suppose that's fair.

Comment: ... which problem, @PatrickCollins, you solve elegantly in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want certain, specific keys to have default values,
you'll need to list those keys somewhere. Calling
[`self.update()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) does what your code does:

```
class SubClass(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SubClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.update({
            'id':None,
            'number':None,
            'oneMoreDefaultKey':None})

instance = SubClass({'city':'New York', 'year':2014})
print instance['id'], instance['year']
```

If you want all keys to have default values, and all
of the default values are the same, then you are
better off using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
import collections
instance = collections.defaultdict(lambda : None, {'city':'New York', 'year':2014})
print instance['id'], instance['year']
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that `defaultdict` is what you want, since that gives you the same value for **any** missing key, rather than just the ones you specify. You're only talking about 3 lines of code either way, so it's tough to imagine it getting too much simpler. However, you can achieve what you're looking for a little bit more concisely like this:

```
class SubClass(dict):
    DEFAULT_KEYS = ['id', 'number', 'oneMoreDefaultKey']
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SubClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.update({key: None for key in self.DEFAULT_KEYS})
```